# Unwanted characters instead of arabic characters

Tags: json, jsp, unicode, character-encoding

I am using a webservice in myproject.I wrote a webservice client method,
 when I call this method I get the json object which has the data. Then I extract that object in jsp and using it
 to display. the problem is: I need to display some arabic characters here which I am
 getting from json object.when I send it to browser it is displaying 
 `ØµÙ€ÙŠØ¯Ù„ÙŠØ© Ø³Ù€Ù€Ø¯ Ù…Ù€Ù€Ù€Ù€Ø£Ø±Ø¨`  like characters instead of arabic characters.

JSON Oject:

```
"results": [
  {
     "attributes": {
      "OBJECTID": "35",
      "FACILITYTYPE": "Pharmacy",
      "FACILITYSUBTYPE": "24 Hr Pharmacy",
      "COMMERCIALNAME_E": "SADD MAARAB PHARMACY",
      "COMMERCIALNAME_A": "صـيدلية ســد مــــأرب",
      "TELEPHONE": "5832625",
      "FAX": "5833266",
      },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
  },
  {
      "attributes": {
      "OBJECTID": "1",
      "FACILITYTYPE": "Pharmacy",
      "FACILITYSUBTYPE": "24 Hr Pharmacy",
      "COMMERCIALNAME_E": "GAYATHY HOSPITAL  PHARMACY",
      "COMMERCIALNAME_A": "صيدلة مستشفى غياثي",
      "TELEPHONE": "28741666",
      "FAX": "28742008",
         },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
  }
]}
```

displaying data in jsp:

```
 <%   for (Object object : results) {
  JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)object;
   if ( jobj != null && jobj.containsKey( "attributes" ) )
       {
    JSONObject att= (JSONObject) jobj.get("attributes");

   %>

<tr ><td ><span><%= att.get("COMMERCIALNAME_E") %></span></td>
<tr ><td ><span><%= att.get("COMMERCIALNAME_A") %></span></td>
<td ><span><%= att.get("TELEPHONE") %></span></td>
<td ><span><%= att.get("FAX") %></span></td>
</tr>
<%}} %>
```

When I run this JSP, I am getting unwanted characters instead of Arabic characters. Where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in top of your JSP.

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This will instruct the server to write and send the data in JSP as UTF-8, and it will also add a response header which instructs the client (browser) to interpret the data as UTF-8. Otherwise the system's default will be used (which is often ISO-8859-1 which doesn't contain Arabic characters).

See also this article for background information and solutions to Unicode problems: [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Hi thank you for giving answer.But I wrote this code already but it is not working.Could you give me other solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

This could have something to do with the encoding of the page. You will certainly need a `unicode` encoding (which includes those special characters) whereas you probably are using the standard `utf-8` (which does not).